# Quantiles of transformed series

Tags: forecasting, random-variable, prediction-interval

Let's have a time series $S_{n}$ of a same market asset.
Let's $R_n = ln(S_n/S_{n-1})$ be an asset returns. So, I could forecast same $\overline{R}_{N+1}, \overline{R}_{N+2}, ... , \overline{R}_{N+j}$, and, of course, quantiles of each $\overline{R}_{N+k}$ by, for example, ARMA-GARCH model. 
1) Is this correct, that pointwise forecast of $S_{N+j}$ be $S_{N} * exp(\overline{R}_{N+1} + \overline{R}_{N+2} + ...)$?
2) How to calculate quantiles for $S_{N+j}$ forecast?

Thank you.